# Find the inflection points of $f(x)={1 +\ln^2 x \over x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Given $$f(x)={1+\ln^2x\over x}, x>0$$
>
> • Find the inflection points of $C_f.$

**Personal work:**

In order to find the inflection points of $C_f$ we first need to find the second derivative and then at which "$x$", $f''(x)=0.$

$${d\over dx}({1+\ln^2 x \over x})={2lnx-1-\ln^2x\over x^2}$$

$${d\over dx}({2lnx-1-\ln^2x\over x^2})=\cdots={2\ln^2-6\ln x+4 \over x^3}$$

or

$${d\over dx}({d\over dx}({1+\ln^2 x \over x}))={2\ln^2-6\ln x+4 \over x^3}$$

I'm struggling on finding the sign of $f'(x)$ and the points that $f''(x)=0.$

Comment: What are curving Points? Do you mean inflection Points?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes, that's what I mean. In Greece, we call them "curving points".

Comment: Hint: set $y = \ln x$. Is a quadratic equation easier?

Comment: That is what i thought, i had luck and have learned the old Greek language.

Comment: @nbubis Your answer seems to solve my question right away. But here's the problem: Let $ω=\ln x$, then: $f''(ω)=f''(x) \iff f''(x)=0 \cdots= ... $. Am I allowed to say $f''(ω)=f''(x)$?

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis Just following up on nbubis's comment. Just get back $x$ as $x=e^{\omega}$, which I believe are $e^{-1}, e^2$

Comment: My mistake, $x = e, e^2$

Comment: @junkquill I did it myself and you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$f''(x)=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{x}-2\ln(x)\cdot \frac{1}{x}\right)x^2-\left(2\ln(x)-1-\ln(x)^2\right)\cdot 2x}{x^4} \\ = \frac{\left(2-2\ln(x)\right)+\left(-2\ln(x)+1+\ln(x)^2\right)\cdot 2}{x^3} \\ = \frac{2-2\ln(x) -4\ln(x)+2+2\ln(x)^2}{x^3} \\ = \frac{2\ln(x)^2 -6\ln(x)+4}{x^3}$$

$f''(x)=0 \Longleftrightarrow 2\ln(x)^2 -6\ln(x)+4=0$

Now, leting $\ln(x) = u$, we have: $$2u^2 -6u+4=0 \implies u=1,2 \\ \implies x=e,e^2$$ which are your possible points of inflection.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: we get $$f''(x)=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{x}-2\ln(x)\cdot \frac{1}{x}\right)x^2-\left(2\ln(x)-1-\ln(x)^2\right)\cdot 2x}{x^4}$$
which is equal to $$f''(x)=\frac{2 \left(\ln ^2(x)-3 \ln (x)+2\right)}{x^3}$$
and Substitute $$t=\ln(x)$$

Comment: Which is equal to $${2\ln^2-6\ln x-4 \over x^3}$$